# "Missing client token" when authenticating with login/pass on Hashicorp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to get login/pass authentication working on Vault.
When I try the method given in the API documentation here: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/userpass/index.html#login

I get this error:

```
$ curl --request POST --data @payload.json https://<myurl>:8200/v1/auth/userpass/login/<mylogin> -k
{"errors":["missing client token"]}
```

And I can't find information on this error. It makes me wonder what happens, because I want to authenticate with login/pass to get the token, so that's just normal to not have it.

Here is the content of the payload.json:

```
{
  "password": "foo"
}
```

Is there any way to login with username/password? This is the only fallback method I have when the user does not know its token.

Thanks!

Comment: May I verify that you have configured Userpass? https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/userpass.html#configuration

Comment: I don't have the hand on the Vault instance I connect to. Is there any way to have this information (is userpass enabled, and is it enabled for me?) through the API?
I think it's enabled though, since we connect through Vault-UI, with login/pass credentials.

Comment: The cli command is `vault auth list`. But you need permission to access it.

Comment: Indeed, I don't have it. That's too bad that discovery APÏ needs specific rights. I don't get the logic behind, but I guess this is either not requested by user, or not thought about, or there's a good reason I don't think of. Well I guess I won't be able to develop a good connector to Vault with that :(

        curl     -H "X-Vault-Token: ***********"     -X GET https://*********:8200/v1/sys/auth -k
        {"errors":["permission denied"]}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so I figured it out by trials.

So the userpass AUTH was indeed disabled. I have to use LDAP auth. With the Vault-UI that is installed, I managed to find the URL to authenticate. If was the following : `https://******:8200/v1/auth/<ldap>/login/<user>`

And that way it's working.

Unfortunately, it does not help in the end. The idea was to synchronize Vault data locally, but the Vault API is really not built for that kind of access. It requires a LOT of requests, and end up being very slow for a few secrets synchronized.

Comment: For the record, it seems Hashicorp does not want to implement a functional API allowing to get all the secrets at once. The plea is that it would be a security issue, which does not make any sense. Not having this API does not prevent downloading the secrets, it just does make it slower, and hitting harder on the backend. This is a poor choice for explaining a poor API... :(

Comment: Got it working thanks to your comment. `<ldap>` refers to whatever name you gave your LDAP authentication service when initially setting it up. If you changed the default `ldap` the URL provided in Hashicorp's documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are logging in under the correct namespace. You will get this error if your authentication method is enabled under something other than the default namespace that your CLI tool is using.

You can specify the namespace with the `-ns=my/namespace/` parameter or the `VAULT_NAMESPACE` environment variable.

For example, if your namespace is "desserts/icecream"

```sh
vault login -ns=desserts/icecream/ -method=userpass username=ian

# OR

export VAULT_NAMESPACE=desserts/icecream/
vault login -method=userpass username=ian
```

Comment: Hit this from hashicorp cloud because the default namespace is "admin".

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was not setting the vault token to the right environment variable.
you have to set the value to `VAULT_TOKEN` so that it uses it in subsequent request my env variable was `Vault_Token` and due to this it was always saying missing client token.

By default, Vault checks for this environment variable to find the token.

`vault kv get --field "ACCESS_KEY_ID" secret/my-secret`